# How to extend Text component in react native elements

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-elements

I'm trying to extend default theme, extending colors works like a charm, but if I try to extend `Text` component with more text styles, this doesnt work, I don't understand what I'm doing wrongm. This is my `react-native-elements.d.ts` file:

#### react-native-elements.d.ts

```js
import 'react-native-elements';
import { ColorValue, StyleProp, TextStyle } from 'react-native';

type ColorSwatch = {
  otherColor: string;
};

declare module 'react-native-elements' {
  export interface Colors extends ColorSwatch {}

  export interface TextProps {
    h5Style: StyleProp<TextStyle>;
  }

  export interface FullTheme {
    colors: RecursivePartial<Colors>;
    Text: Partial<TextProps>;
  }
}
```

I'm trying to implement the theme like this:

```js
import { FullTheme } from 'react-native-elements';

export const theme: FullTheme = {
  Text: {
    h5Style: {
      fontFamily: '',
    },
  }
}
```

This is the TS error in console:

```
Object literal may only specify known properties, but 'h5Style' does not exist in type 'Partial<TextProps>'. Did you mean to write 'h1Style'?
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `h5Style` [doesn't exist](https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/text) on the TextProps interface.

Comment: The idea is to extend the default heme with interface merging: https://reactnativeelements.com/docs/customization#typescript-definitions-extending-the-default-theme you can check the example here and look at how they implmenet new colors and new font styles... that is what I want

Comment: Hey, this has been fixed, and will be available when v4 is released